# Jquery 3.3.1: Не работает функция focusout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Цель:

- по нажатию на элементе добавить форму (работает)
- если убрать фокус с поля добавленной формы, то должен добавится элемент после поля (не работает)

Jquery подключен и работает через сборку webpack.

Код:

```js
'use strict';

const projectCreateWindow =
    '<div class="">' +
        '<div class="">' +
            '<p>Новый проект</p>' +
            '<i class="material-icons"></i>' +
        '</div >' +
        '<form action="" method="POST">' +
            '<label for="name">Наименование проекта</label>' +
            '<input class="" id="name" name="name" type="text">' +
            '<label for="customer">Заказчик</label>' +
            '<input class="" name="customer" type="text">' +
            '<label for="manager">Менеджер проекта</label>' +
            '<input class="" name="manager" type="text">' +
            '<label for="startDate">Дата начала проекта</label>' +
            '<input class="" name="startDate" type="date">' +
            '<label for="endDate">Дата окончания проекта</label>' +
            '<input class="" name="endDate" type="date">' +
            '<label for="description">Описание проекта</label>' +
            '<textarea class="" name="description" type="date"></textarea>' +
            '<input class="" type="submit" value="Создать">' +
            '<input class="" type = "submit" value = "Отмена" >' +
        '</form>' +
    '</div>';

// Selectors
let $submit = $('#submit');
let $name = $('#name');
let $customer = $('customer');
let $manager = $('manager');
let $startDate = $('startDate');
let $endDate = $('endDate');
let $description = $('description');
let $listItemAdd = $('.list-item-add');
let $workplace = $('.workplace');
let $form = $('form');


$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $listItemAdd.one('click', function () {
            $workplace.append(projectCreateWindow);
        });
    });

$(document).on('focusout', $name, function () {
    $(document).on(function () {
        $name.after('<p>Ошибка</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on(function () {` - это что?

Comment: После того, как добавил форму. Разве не нужно обращаться к документу?
Ранее пробовал без этого, тоже не заработало.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Действительно, неправильно было написано. Спасибо.
Изменил кусок на:
`$name.on('focusout',  function () {
    $name.after('<p>Ошибка</p>');
});` 
Не заработало...